# How can we get full path of a tree from mysql event data and hierarchical master data?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a product where user can read through branched stories. In the BI events, we capture only the decision node points where user picks one node over the other. We also have a master data of the story content which has information of the tree. So, our tables look like this:

user_events:

```
user_id link_id     
1000    1       
1000    7            
2000    2            
2000    6
```

So the user with user_id 1000 has clicked on the links 1 and 7, where user 2000 has clicked on links 2 and 6. Depending on this, both users have traversed a different path of nodes. The static path details are stored in a hierarchical data as follows:

Link Info:

```
link_id         from_node    to_node    
1                101          102
2                101          103
3                102          104
4                104          105
5                103          106
6                106          107
7                105          107
8                106          108
9                105          108
```

At nodes 101, 105 and 106, a user can take two different paths and they are 'decision nodes' in the story (101 to 102 or 103; 105 and 106, to 107 or 108). So we capture only those clicks info in the user_events and not the intermediate paths as that paths are defined once the user clicks on a decision node.

Now from the above two tables, I am trying to generate the full path each user has traversed, as follows:

```
user_id    node_id
1000       101
1000       102
1000       104
1000       105
1000       107
2000       101
2000       103
2000       106
2000       107
```

But I am lost here as to how to achieve this. I am trying to join the user events table with link info table, but I could get only the first node there. Can someone please shed some light on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: From what I understood...User 1000 didn't went through  node_id=104, right?

Comment: No, user 1000 went through the following path: 
101 -> 102 -> 104 -> 105 -> 107

Comment: User 1000 clicked on link 1 and 7, so he went from 101 to 102, and from 105 to 107. when did he went through 104?

Comment: @haytem I have added some more context to the question. Please let me know if that clarifies, or I will add more details.

Comment: [Slide 40](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) of Bill Karwin's "Models for Hierarchical Data" might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
With Links as
(Select L1.link_id, L2.to_node as from_node, L1.from_node as to_node
from link_Info L1
inner join
link_Info L2 on L2.to_node=L1.from_node
union all
Select link_id, from_node, to_node 
from Link_info)
Select E.user_id, L.from_node as node_id
from user_events E inner join Links L
on L.link_id=E.link_id 
union all        
Select E.user_id, L.to_node as node_id
from user_events E inner join Links L
on L.link_id=E.link_id
```